# Error Spotting : I am better adapted to the climate than you

Tags: ellipsis, exam-questions, comparative-constructions

What's the error in following sentence?

> I am better adapted to the climate than you.

The book says it's error free but I guess it's printing mistake because from what I have learned is that when we compare, we compare two equal things so the correct sentence should be : *I am better adapted to the climate than you **are**.* Am I right ?

Consider this example:
Incorrect:

> The streets of London are cleaner than New York.

Correct:

> The streets of London are cleaner than those of New York.

Comment: I like your version better, but I think the book is correct that the ending verb is optional.  Perhaps someone with more grammar knowledge than I (have) will give a more informed opinion.

Comment: @Andrew I am saying so because consider this example  if I say The streets of London are cleaner than Newyork then this sentence is wrong . Correct sentence will be The streets of London are cleaner than those of Newyork.

Comment: "The streets of London are cleaner than New York's. "

Comment: @user212388 I think your examples are better *style* but I suspect they're not more *grammatical*.

Answer (score 4):

In your examples the parts that are left are are *assumed*, and it is a standard construction to do it this way.

> I am better adapted to the climate than you *(are adapted)*.
>   The streets of London are cleaner than New York' *(are clean)*.
>   I am taller than you *(are tall)*.

Comment: To be explicit. Both sentences that the OP says are "incorrect" are perfectly well formed complete English sentences.

Comment: It is also important to note that the trailing verb *are* is optional.  Both versions are commonly heard.  The trailing adjectives (*clean, tall, etc.*) are NOT optional.  In my experience they are never spoken.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences involve a form of ellipsis called [comparative deletion](http://This%20is%20afomr%20of%20ellipsis%20called%20%5Bcomparative%20deletion%5D%5B1%5D). Unlike some other forms of ellipsis, comparative deletion allows the omission of non-identical verb, for example am/are, so the section in brackets in the following sentence can be deleted:

> I am better adapted to the climate than you [are adapted]

This sentence would never be written in full, but it could be written with or without [are]- it's a question of personal style which you would choose and, for a particular person, might depend on the context.

> The streets of London are cleaner than New York [is clean].

This sentence is grammatically correct, but there may well be a semantic error, because it compares **the streets of** London with **the whole of** New York.

If the intention is to compare streets with streets, this could be done in two ways:

> The streets of London are cleaner than **New York's** [streets]
> The streets of London are cleaner than **those of** New York.

Note the apostrophe-s in the first version. The second version is more formal the first.